# Merge array and remove duplicate using specific key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have following arrays

```
array:3 [
  0 => array:3 [
    0 => "EN"
    1 => "ENGLISH"
    2 => 1
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    0 => "JA"
    1 => "JAPANESE"
    2 => 1
  ]
  2 => array:3 [
    0 => "JA"
    1 => "JAPANESE"
    2 => 0
  ]
]
```

I want to remove the duplicates but only check on key **0** and **1**.
When I used `array_unique()` it does not work.

The result I expect is

```
array:2 [
      0 => array:3 [
        0 => "EN"
        1 => "ENGLISH"
        2 => 1
      ]
      1 => array:3 [
        0 => "JA"
        1 => "JAPANESE"
        2 => 1
      ]
    ]
```

The last array was removed, because it has the same **JA** and **JAPANESE**, and the one that has **1** remains.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use use the unique indexes as key,

```
$result = [];
foreach($array as $v)
{
    $result[$v[0] . $v[1]] = $v;
}
$result = array_values($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

using collection you can do this by

```
// using collection
$collection = collect([ ["EN", "ENGLISH", 1],["JP", "JAPAN", 1], ["JP", "JAPAN", 1] ]);

// then filtering the value
$filtered = $collection->filter(function ($value, $key) {
    return $value[2] == 1;
});

// then unique only by the acronym ( en , jp )
$unique = $filtered->unique(0);

// you may also add the 2nd value to determine it's uniqueness
$unique = $filtered->unique(function ($item) {
    return $item[0].$item[1];
});

// getting all the uniqued values
$unique->values()->all();
```